# ReactJS: how put my floatting element -textB- and my initial's placed text -textA- on the same baseline?

Tags: css, reactjs

here the demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-i8c9en

I would the two text to be on the same baseline. I have tried to play with vertical-align and other properties and so far I fail to achieve a same-baseline's rendering.

```js
class App extends React.Component { 
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="component">
        <h3 
          className="text_a"
        >
          textA{" "} 
          <span className="text_b">
            textB
          </span> 
        </h3>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.component {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px;
}

.text_a {
  font-size: 5em;
}

.text_b {
  /* width:100%; */
  float: right;
  /* position:absolute; */
  right: 3vw;
  /* margin-right:5vw; */
  /* margin-top:7.5vh; */
  /* position:relative; */
  /* float:right;
    clear:both; */
  /* padding-right:10vw; */
  /* vertical-align:middle; */
  font-size: 0.60em;
  color: rgb(54, 0, 18);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use flex and align items to the baseline.

```
.text_a{
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  font-size:5em;
}
```

`vertical-align` doesn't work on block style elements. Here's additional information on that: https://christopheraue.net/design/vertical-align

**Edit:** 
Taking another look at your code, these elements should have been aligned to the baseline with their default styles. You can still use flex, but just removing the `float` would work too.

```
.text_a {
  font-size: 5em;
}

.text_b {
  font-size: 0.60em;
  color: rgb(54, 0, 18);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answers, in fact I want the float to maintain my element on the right

Comment: I maybe don't quite understand what you're trying to achieve since the elements will stay inline (aka "on the right") without `float`, but keep in mind that `float` will be ignored when inside a `flex` container. In general the need for `float` has been diminished with newer css like `flex` and `grid`.

Comment: yes I understand, I am trying to push textB on screen's right-edge and let the textA on the rest of the element's surface, you can see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58962894/9817602

Answer (score 0):

add css property line-height to text_b

```
.text_b {
    line-height: 110px; /* adjust according to your need */
}
```

reference: 
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
text_a{
position:relative
}
```

```
text_b{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;   //make it responsive i've just hard coded or else you can leave as it if it works
}
```

because h3 has some default styling so it becomes tedious to overwrite it

Answer (score 0):

Remove the float from `.text_b` and give it a `margin-left: 3vw`:

```js
class App extends React.Component { 
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="component">
        <h3 className="text_a">
          textA{" "} 
          <span className="text_b">
            textB
          </span> 
        </h3>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.component {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px;
}

.text_a {
  font-size: 5em;
}

.text_b {
  margin-left: 3vw;
  font-size: 0.60em;
  color: rgb(54, 0, 18);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, in fact I want the float to maintain my element on the right

Comment: @Webwoman you can push it to the right by giving h3 a `display:flex` and `.text_b` `margin-left:auto`

Comment: yes but it offsets the words, see here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-5jsdlb?file=style.css

Answer (score 0):

My solution: using a container with flex's displaying -thanks to sallf for the idea-, then align all the items on baseline, then use flex-basis to distribute the space between the items, hence allowing to maintain my textB on the right's edge of the screen.

Demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ypdmxu

ReactJS's snippet:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom'; 
import './style.css';

class App extends Component { 
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="component">
        <h3 
          className="text_container"
        > 
          <span className="text_a">
            textA {" "} 
          </span>
          <span className="text_b">
            textB
          </span> 
        </h3>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

CSS' snippet:

```
.component{ 
  padding:50px;
}
.text_container{  
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  font-size:5em;
}

.text_a{
    flex-basis: 95%;
}
.text_b{  
    font-size:0.60em;
    color:rgb(54, 0, 18); 
}
```